# emit to all sockets not working Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to emit a message to all sockets connected to my server using socket.io. So far, the code is as follows:

> ```
>     if(electionExists) {
>       var connectedClients = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[electionRequested].sockets;
>       for(client in connectedClients) {
>           socket.to(client).emit("isVoteValid", {voteToValidate: voteToValidate});
>       }
>     }
> ```
>
> I made sure that it enters the if(electionExists) condition. Also, I've printed out the array of connected clients, which looks like this:

```
{ SdiVoIUuGfFL5AJXAAAA: true, 'wLh-EfkAIrWpjx6nAAAC': true }
```

and just for the sake of it, I printed each client in the loop, which leads to this:

```
SdiVoIUuGfFL5AJXAAAA
wLh-EfkAIrWpjx6nAAAC
```

Therefore, I'm led to believe that the problem is not on getting the proper socket id's. However, the emit event doesn't work. On the client side I have this:

```
  socket.on("isVoteValid", function(obj) {
    console.log("it enters isVoteValid");
  });
```

which is really, really simple but the console.log never happens. I really can't see why it is not working. Anyone got an idea?

Comment: try `socket.broadcast.emit` to send to all clients without using a for-loop

Comment: didn't work :( Nothing showed up in the console.log

Comment: Since you're just trying to emit to all the sockets in a room, why don't you just broadcast to the room?

Comment: I tried stepping through the code for  `socket.to()` and it seems that it is used for broadcasting to the connected sockets in a room. Not for individual socket. so u should pass in the room id for it `socket.to(electionRequested)` let me know if it works

Comment: @TeogenesMoura I don't think the solution that you accepted is very correct. You are broadcasting the msg to everyone connected to the default namespace...

Comment: @SamuelToh that is correct, as my question was regarding to sending a message to all connected sockets on my server. I apologize if that was maybe some sloppy way of asking, but I think it does have the same meaning as sending a message to everyone connected to the default namespace

Comment: @TeogenesMoura ok. So you are wanting to do a broadcast then you are safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to broadcast your message then use following code

```
if(electionExists) {
      socket.broadcast.emit("isVoteValid", {voteToValidate: voteToValidate});
}
```

or you can also use this

```
if(electionExists) {
      io.sockets.emit("isVoteValid", {voteToValidate: voteToValidate});
}
```

Comment: No idea really :(